# Как авторизовывать пользователя через google sign in только когда он существует в firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, auth

Я использую два пакета для авторизации через google firebase

1. [google_sign_in: ^4.5.1](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in)
2. [firebase_auth: ^0.16.1](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth)

Когда я вызываю метод **signInWithCredential**

```
final FirebaseUser user =
        (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
```

Это создаёт мне запись в таблице авторизаций firebase. Есть ли какой-то способ давать авторизоваться через гугл только, если учётная запись существует?

Comment: А пользователей вы сами планируете добавлять в firebase?

Comment: Да, но с вэба. В приложении только авторизация, без создания учётной записи.

Comment: насколько я помню, в самом Firebase можно задавать правила. После чего нужно будет только обрабатывать ошибки в приложении.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/99